# Defining non-writable properties without Object.defineProperty?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

So I know you can do this:

```
var obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'staticProp', {
    value: 'I will never change',
    writable: 'false'
});
```

And I know you can do this:

```
var obj = {
    get gettableProp(){
        return 'gettable!'
    }
}
```

Is there a way to define non-writable/enumerable/configurable properties declaratively instead of using Object.defineProperty(), the way you'd define a getter or setter?

The reason I ask is because I have a function that gets passed an object like this:

```
ObjectProcessor({
    // A bunch of properties
})
```

I'd really like to be able to keep that simple syntax for cases when I'd want to include non-writable or non-enumerable properties, rather than having to do

```
var obj = {}
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'staticProp', {
    value: 'I will never change',
    writable: 'false'
});
ObjectProcessor(obj);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to define non-writable/enumerable/configurable properties declaratively instead of using Object.defineProperty(), the way you'd define a getter or setter?

No.

<sub>(there is [`Object.defineProperties`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties), but I guess that's not what you are looking for)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no other method (except for `Object.defineProperties` and `Object.create` that allow you to provide multiple of these descriptors).

> I'd really like to be able to keep that simple syntax

Notice that `Object.defineProperty` returns the passed object, so you can simplify your code to

```
ObjectProcessor(Object.defineProperty({}, 'staticProp', {
    value: 'I will never change',
    writable: 'false'
}));
```

and avoid introducing that extra `obj` variable.

Comment: That's true, it hadn't occurred to me that defineProperty/ies returns the object. I just don't like how the moment you want to pass a single read-only prop to your object, it instantly makes the syntax for every property a million times more verbose (especially since the defaults are all false).

Comment: …and of course, you can always write a little helper function if you feel writing repetitive code.

Answer (score 0):

With a naming convention, you can build it into your ObjectProcessor:

```
var prefix = 'readonly_';

function ObjectProcessor(obj) {
    Object.keys(obj).filter(function (name) {
        // find property names which match your convention
        return name.indexOf(prefix) === 0;
    }).forEach(function (name) {
        // make the new property readonly
        Object.defineProperty(obj, name.substring(prefix.length), {
            value: obj[name],
            writable: false
        });

        // remove the old, convention-named property
        delete obj[name];
    });

    // remaining ObjectProcessor logic...
}
```

This lets you handle writable and readonly properties:

```
ObjectProcessor({
    readonly_id: 1,
    name: 'Foo'
});
```

Comment: That's sort of what I'm thinking, or maybe passing in a properties object that, if it exists, would be passed to an Object.defineProperties call. Basically you'd define any properties and accessors you could with the normal object declaration syntax, and stuff anything that needs to be read-only or non-enumerated into that special properties object. I'll experiment with those two approaches and see which one works better.

Comment: @Zacqary I think a second object for readonly properties is a good idea, because it eliminates the chance that someone accidentally and erroneously uses your naming convention.

Comment: @Zacqary Adding enumerable, configurable, ... will probably complicate things; at some point, it will might be easier to just use `Object.defineProperties`.  Good luck!